# How can I duplicate patient information in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design

I am working for a hospital building a patient recording system on Microsoft Access. 
One of the Doctor's requests is that when they are seeing patients that are siblings, is there any way that they do not have to type in duplicate information for these relatives? (Address, phone number, town of residence, etc...)

I understand that the ID number will change for each patient. Say the form goes like this:

1) Does patient have other siblings at risk? (Y/N)
2) If so, how many?

Depending on the digit that answers question two, could I duplicate the primary patient's information so that it exists in 3 different files? The doctor is adamant that it would be easier to go back and alter a few fields than it would be to type them repetitively.

Is this possible? Are there any shortcuts to doing so?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a table called RESIDENCES, which would have an id, address, phone number etc. A patient record would include a foreign key to this table's id. When a sibling is added, the sibling record would include the same foreign key. The tricky part of doing this would be in the user interface: when a new patient is about to be added, you will have to ask whether this patient is a sibling of someone. If yes, you will have to ask who the sibling is, then copy the 'residences' foreign key; if no, you will have to display a dialog which allows the 'residencies' data to be added.

But what happens if a sibling changes address or has a separate telephone number? In that case, the contact details of each person would be stored in the patient record, without a 'residences' table; your user interface could include a function which copies contact data from record to record.

I think that this approach is better because each person has his own contact data which is independent from everyone else. The problem which you stated is more an *interface* problem (how do I add this functionality to make things easier for the users?) than a *data modelling* problem (how should the data be stored?).